# send email when check box changes state

Tags: infopath, designer-workflow

I have the following requirement

I have an infopath FORM where there is a check box for urgent. when this field changes to true, i.e selected, an email is sent. at first it seamed obvious and I created the following workflow:

wait for field change
then send email

and set the workflow "on change"

However I have additional column called "comments" on the form library which is used to add comments to the item in question. the problem is that when someone adds comments in this column the workflow runs again and the email is sent. how can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an additional column as test and the defsult value is 1. 
Then you can create the condition , if test =1 && urgent = true , 
send email  and then change the test value to 0.

The reason of changing test column value, is it will stop running the workflow to send email. As , only 1 neeeds as value of test field and we changed it after running workflow....
Hope it may help... i had similar situation like this although not exactly same... but this idea will be helpful..in your case hopefully....

Comment: I did that tecnique previously and it works but only once. if another user togles back the check box and then back on, then workflow will not run, you guessed it because now the test column is 0. nevertheless is an improvement,

Comment: I think u already checked and made sure u selected the right option , in starting workflow condition...if not, can try and check if it works...

Comment: the actions are the following: it currentitem:Urgent equals YES AND current item:UrgentDummy equals YES send email, then set current item:UrgentDummy to No. the wf is set to "on change" and "on creation". again this works but only on first time the user clicks urgent checkbox. if for some reason someone after the wf runs, unchecks the box and then somone checks it back on the, the wf will not run second time.